# C# Get MAX value

Tags: c#, webmatrix

Is this the correct way to get the MAX value (id) from the database and then substrat 6 to it?

```
var photoso = db.QuerySingle("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Photos");
var toto = photoso - 6;
```

It is telling me that I can not use a '-' opperator between a WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord and Int

Comment: i think it's correct.

Comment: That will do it but there are edge cases such as what happens if the table is empty, what if Id < 6, is a negative value valid, etc to consider...

Comment: There is of course no guarantee that `Max(Id)-6` is (still) a valid Id.

Comment: @DeanWard - a negative id is an Id too. But when `Max(id)==6`  it is indeed flaky.

Comment: I don't know, It is telling me that I can not use a '-' opperator between a WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord and Int

Comment: O, and setting `NewRecord.Id = photoso+1`  is of course not concurrency safe. It will work on your PC but not on a webserver.

Comment: @Brunodeluk - if you want an answer to that, use _edit_ and add it to the question. Comments don't count here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`photoso` would return a collection of data to your. To get one object, use its name in the Collection. Just like accessing an object in Array or List using its Index number.

You code is as

```
            photoso           -   6
WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord and Int
```

Try this code instead

```
var photoso = db.QueryValue("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Photos");
var toto = (photoso - 6); // get the column Id from the Collection data
```

This would work.

Here is a tutorial for that by Mike Brind: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/214/How-To-Check-If-A-Query-Returns-Data-In-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

Comment: The photoso variable is a single scalar value and doesn't accept the 'Id' property. Replace `var toto = (photoso.Id - 6);` with `var toto = (photoso - 6);`

Comment: @GmG, yeah I almost forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be

```
var photoso = db.QueryValue("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Photos");
var toto = photoso - 6;
```

Look at the difference between QuerySingle and QueryValue in the [Database class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the `var` keyword for `photoso`.

It may not be an int so you would need to cast the returned max value to an int and then subtract 6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that query seems fine, but that error would suggest that there is a type mismatch.

I would try extracting the value from `photoso`, so that it is an `int`, or casting `photoso` as an int. Try using `photoso.Id` or similar property to get the numerical value out of the photoso query result.

Of course, that's assuming that subtracting 6 from the resulting Id will still be valid, and that Id is a numerical value.